Неправильно работает вывод сообщений об ошибке при регистрации
Пишу регистрацию на nodejs. Весь скрипт работает корректно. Но не могу настроить вывод сообщений в случае, если email уже зарегистрирован и т.д. Хочу использовать flash для этого. Но после нажатия на "Зарегистрироваться" ничего не происходит. redirect перенаправляет на /registration-error, в нем только текст в консоль выводится, а нужная страница не появляется. Как это исправить?
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {sqlconnect} = require('./modules/sql')
const {checkPassword} = require('./modules/check-password');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const flash = require('connect-flash'); 

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(flash());

const sessions_options = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "sessions",
    password: ""
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(sessions_options);

//подключаем сессию
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'fdFNK234F&^ef==wefdfh',
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    })
)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
app.get('/support', (req, res) => {
    res.render('support');
});
app.get('/contacts', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contacts');
});
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile');
});
app.get('/registration', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('auntefication/registration', {
        title: 'Регистрация',
        error: req.flash('error')
    });
});
app.get('/registration-error', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('registration-error сработал')
    res.render('auntefication/registration', {
        title: 'Регистрация',
        error: req.flash('error')
    });
});

app.post('/registration', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

    let error_code = 0;

    const email      = req.body.email,
          name       = req.body.name,
          last_name  = req.body.last_name,
          pass       = req.body.pass,
          repass     = req.body.repass;
          

    error_code = checkPassword(pass, repass, error_code);

    if (error_code != 0) {
        switch (error_code) {
            case 1:
                req.flash('error', 'Пароль должен содержать только латинские символы, хотя бы одну заглавную букву, 2 цифры и хотя бы один специальный символ!');
                return res.redirect('/registration-error');
                break;
            case 2:
                req.flash('error', 'Пароли не совпадают');
                return res.redirect('/registration-error');
                break;
        }
    } else {

        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(pass, 10);

        let query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM users WHERE email =?) AS emailExists';
        const connection = sqlconnect();
    
        connection.query(query, [email], (err, result) => {
            
            if (result[0].emailExists === 1) {
                message = {
                    'code' : 2,
                    'text': "Пользователь с таким email уже существует!"
                }
                res.json(message);
            } else {
              let insert = 'INSERT INTO users (email, name, last_name, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
              
              connection.query(insert, [email, name, last_name, hashPassword]);
            res.render('auntefication/auth');
            }
          })

    }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    
});

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.render('auntefication/auth');
});

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

Структура проекта

